# Zero all values except max in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an array `[0.3, 0.5, 0.79, 0.2, 0.11].`

I want to convert all values to zero except the max value. So the resulting array would be:
`[0, 0, 0.79, 0, 0]`

What would be the best way to do this in a Tensorflow graph?

Comment: And if you array is `[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]`?

Comment: Take the 1st one, I guess. What is behavior of argmax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the behavior of `tf.argmax()` and want only **one max** in case of ties, you can do:

> tf.sparse_to_dense(tf.argmax(a),tf.cast(tf.shape(a), dtype=tf.int64),
>   tf.reduce_max(a))

```
a = tf.constant([0.3, 0.5, 0.79, 0.79, 0.11])

out = tf.sparse_to_dense(tf.argmax(a),tf.cast(tf.shape(a), dtype=tf.int64), tf.reduce_max(a))
```

**Output:**

```
[0.   0.   0.79 0.   0.  ]
```

Comment: I'm getting -InvalidArgumentError: output_shape has incorrect number of elements: 2 should be: 1
  [[node SparseToDense (defined at <ipython-input-895-b5fc7481a86a>:24) ]] error after using above code. can you help me out with this one

Comment: in tf 2.1, this doesn't work as `sparse_to_dense` is not a thing anymore. Using `tf.sparse.to_dense` requires to use a sparse tensor so this becomes a little bit more involved.

Comment: The old version is still accessible as [`tf.compat.v1.sparse_to_dense`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/sparse_to_dense).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep all occurences of the maximum, you could use

```
cond = tf.equal(a, tf.reduce_max(a))
a_max = tf.where(cond, a, tf.zeros_like(a))
```

If you want to keep only one occurrence of the maximum, you could use

```
argmax = tf.argmax(a)
a_max = tf.scatter_nd([[argmax]], [a[argmax]], tf.to_int64(tf.shape(a)))
```

However according to [the doc of `tf.argmax`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argmax),

> Note that in case of ties the identity of the return value is not guaranteed

As I understand it, the maximum that is kept may not be the first or the last -- and may not even be the same if run twice on the same array.

Answer (score 2):

use `max` to find max value:

```
my_list = [0.3, 0.5, 0.79, 0.2, 0.11]
m = max(my_list)
```

then use `list-comprehension`:

```
[0 if i != m else i for i in my_list]
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 0, 0.79, 0, 0]
```

Comment: To my understanding, he is asking how to do it using TF arrays I suppose.

Comment: Yes. I am asking about Tensorflow implementing in a TF graph.